# How to set the signup page as homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just installed Devise in my RoR app.
I want my root site ( http://site.com ) displays the devise sign up page.

If the user is already logged, then redirect to the user dashboard. But, if an user go to http://site.com/dashboard and is not logged, then redirect to the home page, where the user can see the sign up.

How can I do this?

Thank you

UPDATE:

In my routes.rb there is

```
root :to => 'users#index'
```

and this in my users_controller:

```
def index
    if user_signed_in?
      render 'dashboard'
    else
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end
```

It's correct?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `routes.rb`

```
   authenticate :user do
      root :to => "user_dashboard#show"
    end
    root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
```

Change the `"user_dashboard#show"` to your controller#method for your dashboard.

authenticate is a devise specific method for your routes file.

Source: 
http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#authenticate-instance_method

Comment: What's authenticate? Should not I use before_filter?

Comment: authenticate is a devise specific method that you can use for your routes... see here: http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#authenticate-instance_method

Comment: That solution works as well, I was just providing a nice way of doing it via your routing file.

Comment: With your code I've get: undefined method `authenticate' when I go to /

Comment: hmm works fine for me. What version of Devise are you running/did you restart rails?

Comment: 1.1.rc1, probably I need to upgrade.

Comment: Yes you do need to upgrade, as seen here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.1.rc1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb Your version does not support authenticate. For various reason(including security), I'd upgrade ASAP.

Comment: When a user go to http://site.com/ and is logged, there's a way to redirect to site.com/dashboard ?

Comment: With my code that I posted, the logic is as follows: If the user is logged in, set the root path/and follow it, otherwise use the specified root, which is the login page for devise.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But if possible I want example.com/dashboard. With the "/dashboard". I'm new to Rails, thank you for all, however. :)

Comment: Yes, just set root "user_dashboard#show" to "dashboard#index" or whatever your `controller#method` is for for that dashboard. It will then change the url to example.com/dashboard

Comment: I've just put this in my routes.rb:   authenticate :user do
    root :to => "people#index"
  end
  
  root :to => "devise/registrations#new" But when I log out and go to /, the server redirects me to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in. Do you know why this?

Comment: Yes, because `root :to => "devise/sessions#new"` does this. It provides the login functionality that you wanted, however it doesn't stay at example.com. If you wanted to stay on site.com/, you should use your solution.

Comment: Nope man, read my last comment. I've put devise/registrations#new. But it always redirect me to the sign in form. Mmh